# Autofac DI with Sitecore 10.3

Tags: dependency-injection, autofac

We are currently doing sitecore upgrade and but there are something broken with `autofac DI` integration with sitecore. we created our own serviceProviderBuilder which extends `Sitecore.DependencyInjection.BaseServiceProviderBuilder`, we then patch it through sitecore config, but it throws runtime errors

> [LockRecursionException: Recursive read lock acquisitions not allowed
> in this mode.]

Our custom service provider builder as shown in below

```
public class AutofacServiceProviderBuilder : Sitecore.DependencyInjection.BaseServiceProviderBuilder
    {
        protected override IServiceProvider BuildServiceProvider(IServiceCollection serviceCollection)
        {
            var builder = new ContainerBuilder();

            builder.Populate(serviceCollection);

            // Register All Controllers In The Current Scope
            builder.RegisterControllers(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies());
            builder.RegisterApiControllers(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies());

            // Register Modules
            builder.RegisterType<MemberOnlineMediatorService>().As<IMemberOnlineMediator>();
            builder.RegisterType<InteractionMaintenanceService>().As<IInteractionMaintenanceService>();
            builder.RegisterType<MemberStatementsService>().As<IMemberStatementsService>();
            builder.RegisterType<DbHealthCheckService>().As<IDbHealthCheckService>();

            // Register all Autofac Modules from assemblies
            builder.RegisterAssemblyModules(AppDomainScanner.AllAssemblies);
            
            builder.RegisterFilterProvider();

            // Register AutoMapper
            AutoMapperConfiguration(builder);

            // Register Additional Dependencies
            RegisterAbstractValidators(builder);

            // Build container
            var container = builder.Build();
            return new AutofacServiceProvider(container);
        }
    }
```

Comment: please, provide your version of BaseServiceProviderBuilder

Comment: it is in sitecore.kernel.dll (10.3)

Comment: also tried this autofacserviceproviderbuilder with clean sitecore vanilla instance, it throws the same error.

Comment: did you check showconfig on your environment? Just to be sure that you don't have 2 processors that registor DI

Comment: unable to load sitecore login screen at all due to that exception. I tried to patch on sitecore vanilla instance, same error.

Comment: could you show how registration look on vainla config and how you are patching it